# Next js version 10 to 13 upgrade

Tags: next.js, next.js13

This is pages/my _app.js file:

```
import { Provider } from 'next-auth/client';
import '../styles/globals.css';
import 'react-perfect-scrollbar/dist/css/styles.css';

import LayoutWrapper from '../components/Layout/layout-wrapper';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Provider session={pageProps.session}>
      <LayoutWrapper {...pageProps}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </LayoutWrapper>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

In version 13 of Next.js, I'm transitioning to using a different layout structure in an app/layout.js file, like this:

```
import { AuthProvider } from './Providers';
import '../styles/globals.css';
import LayoutWrapper from '../components/Layout/layout-wrapper';

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <html lang="en">
        <body>
          <AuthProvider>
            <LayoutWrapper>{children}</LayoutWrapper>
          </AuthProvider>
        </body>
      </html>
    </>
  );
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that in the version 13 layout, there is no direct access to pageProps. How can I pass pageProps to the LayoutWrapper component within the new layout structure in Next.js v13?

My components/Layout/layout-wrapper.js file looks like this:

```
import DefaultLayout from './default';
import HomeLayout from './home';

const layouts = {
  default: DefaultLayout,
  home: HomeLayout
};

const LayoutWrapper = props => {
  // to get the text value of the assigned layout of each component
  const Layout = layouts[props.children.type.layout];
  console.log('Layout', Layout);
  // if we have a registered layout render children with said layout
  if (Layout != null) {
    return <Layout {...props}>{props.children}</Layout>;
  }
  //  if not render children with fragment
  return <HomeLayout {...props}>{props.children}</HomeLayout>;
};

export default LayoutWrapper;
```

How can I modify my code in version 13 to pass pageProps to the LayoutWrapper component as I did in version 10?

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

The `pageProps` used by `pages` router (in Next.js `_app.js`) is used to store the result of `getServerSideProps` or `getStaticProps` prefetch calls.

Since in `app` router those functions are not available, there is no need for `pageProps` as well.

---

If your intention is to apply different layouts for different routes, you can do by creating multiple child layouts.

- `app/layout.js`
- `app/home/layout.js`
- `app/user/layout.js`

The root layout (`app/layout.js`) will be applied to both home and user paths (along with their respective layouts).